# matToolTip no show with or without filtering/ngFor

Tags: angular

See https://angular-bad-mattooltip.stackblitz.io/

I've checked out this [regarding ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49633413/angular-material-mattooltip-does-not-display-when-using-ngfor-function), and [gitHub](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10039)

Would like to know solution for both standalone and ngFor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should always attach code to your question, if links go stale it's just guessing what your issue is.

The reason that you do not see the tooltips, is because you did not add any material theme to your app. For instance in your `styles.css` you can declare a predefined theme:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bad-mattooltip-zcd7ea?file=src%2Fstyles.css)

Comment: so **theme** is required for matTooltip in addition to `BrowserAnimationsModule` and `MatTooltipModule`?

Comment: @Jeb50 yes, a theme adds the required styling for all the material components, including positioning and dimensions. Not just the colors and typography